# PHP explode on string throws NULL object when accessing the array

Tags: php, string, null, explode

I'm trying to explode a string for a video playtime. My Code is:

```
$viedeolaenge = $file['playtime_string']; // $videolaenge is now string 00:06
var_dump($viedeolaenge); // string(4) "0:06"
$minuten_sekunden = explode(":",$videolaenge);
var_dump($minuten_sekunden); // array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
```

I've tried to access the array via

```
    $minuten_sekunden[0] -> returns string(0) ""
    and 
    $minuten_sekunden[1] -> returns NULL
```

and was now wondering, why this is not working... 
when I explode the string with seperator ":" and my string is "00:06", then

**$minuten_sekunden[0] should return "00"**

and

**$minuten_sekunden[1] should return "06"**

at least in my logic... what am I missing?

Comment: “`$viedeolaenge`”…? You didn’t seriously just typo this, did you?

Comment: WOW... I'm sry guys it's late...

Comment: You should get a notice of undefined variable. Unless you have errors turned off.

Comment: If you have not already done so, get yourself an IDE that has syntax and spell checking. Net beans for instance would have warned you about the variable $viedeolaenge not being initialised and so pointing to a typo in this case.

Comment: since php XXX errors and notice messages don't show up in frontend, they got logged serverside... missed checking this.

Comment: Correct, but as you are developing it is safe for you to override this default setting in your php.ini and display errors. Ofcourse, you would not want this on a production server.

Comment: And you’re not developing live on a production server, *riiiiiiiight?!*

Comment: Another option (if you dont want an ide or displaying error (and providing you have ssh access to the server is for you to tail the log file, not sure how you would do it under windows, but linux is very simple.

Comment: No, I'm not @deceze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the OP just needs to turn on the display of errors, i.e. turn on [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).  Then they would see that the variable is misspelled and therefore a notice appears about an undefined variable.

> Notice: Undefined variable: videolaenge in /in/emNVQ on line 5

If you correct the variable's spelling then you'll get the desired result:

```
<?php

$videolaenge = "00:06";
var_dump($videolaenge); // string(4) "0:06"
$minuten_sekunden = explode(":",$videolaenge);
var_dump($minuten_sekunden); // array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
```

Live code [here](https://3v4l.org/LZc3O)

Note: this isn't really about correct spelling but *consistent* spelling. So, I just made all three variable references have the spelling indicated in the notice.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer @slevy1, as mentioned above it's a typo.. while error reporting is just logged in a serverside file, I missed checking the log for the typovar. Maybe I'll set up an E-Mail alert for every notice/error the server logs, so I don't miss this types of errors in the future :)

Comment: @KerimYagmurcu You're welcome :)  Also, you may want to check out this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php